# Particle-JS Responsive canvas height issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, particles.js

I've been working with a Bootstrap portfolio where I am trying to use particle.js on the profile picture.

I set the particles inside a `DIV` and gave it a bg-image with profile photo. The fact is, when I reload the screen on XL screen and resize the screen to xl > lg > md, it stays fine. But when The screen size increased to md > lg > xl, the canvas height doesn't decrease according to its parent. Please HELP!

Here is the link:

https://sabbir030.github.io/portfolio/

Canvas Height Issue

[image]

```
<header id="main-header">
    <!-- full row for image to the left and others to the right -->
    <div class="row no-gutters">
      <!-- images to the left with 4 col -->
      <div class=" col-md-5 col-lg-4">

       <!-- PARTICLE JS WITH PROFILE PICTURE -->

        <div id="particles-js"></div>

      </div>

      <!-- Name and Menu to the right with 8 col -->
      <div class=" col-md-7 col-lg-8">

      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
```

```
#particles-js {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #b61924;
    background-image: url('../img/profile.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> You can define `max-width`, `max-height` and `margin: 0 auto` on `#particles-js` id for centering particle div.

```
#particles-js {
  max-width: 380px;
  max-height: 401px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me

```js
// the element in which you want to play the particles animation (in my case the body element)
var particleAnimationContainer = document.querySelector('body');

// initialize the dimensions of the animation container; in my case with the avalaible screen dimensions
var screenWIDTH = screen.availWidth;
var screenHEIGHT = screen.availHeight;

particleAnimationContainer.width(screenWIDTH);
particleAnimationContainer.height(screenHEIGHT);

//launch the animation particlesConfig  provided in particles.json      
particlesJS("id-of-body", particlesConfig);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put particles js canvas to a specific height or width simply add a wrapper div  and make particle.js options add attribute style

> position : "absolute"
> and make wrapper div
> position:"relative"
> and give your height and width